# Need to filter 2 lists & add into seprate list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have 2 list:

- `avaliableRoomType` - [Standard, SuperDeluxe ]
- `wholeRoomtype` - [Standard, SuperDeluxe, Deluxe]

I need to filter this & add into separate list `unavailableRoomtype` - [Deluxe]

```
for(int j = 0; j <  avaliableRoomType.size()  ; j++) {

        for(int i = 0; i < wholeRoomtype.size(); i++) {

            String tempAv = avaliableRoomType.get(j);
            String tempHotelRoomId = wholeRoomtype.get(i);

            if(!tempAv.equals(tempHotelRoomId)){


            unavailableRoomtype.add(tempHotelRoomId);


            }

        }

    }
```

but i have duplicate values.

Comment: In your scenario, you can use `list.contains(roomType)` to verify whether you already have an item in the list. Also if you don't want duplicates you can use a Set

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve... I do not really know what your lists contain but I think you will end up with the union of those two lists.

Comment: @Vakh yep I got union in other word messup instead of filter this

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> unavailableRoomtype = new ArrayList<>();

for (String roomType : wholeRoomtype) {
  if (!avaliableRoomType.contains(roomType)) {
    unavailableRoomtype.add(roomType);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Set`s instead of `List`s:

```
Set<String>   roomTypes;        
Set<RoomType> availableRoomType;
Set<RoomType> unavailableRoomType;
```

**Example implementation**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Set<String> roomTypes           = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    final Set<String> availableRoomType   = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    final Set<String> unavailableRoomType = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    roomTypes.add("Standard");
    roomTypes.add("Deluxe");
    roomTypes.add("SuperDeluxe");
    // .. other entries

    // determine what room types are available
    availableRoomType.add("Standard");
    availableRoomType.add("SuperDeluxe");


    // your filtering for unavailable room types
    roomTypes.stream()
            .filter(e -> !availableRoomType.contains(e))
            .forEach(unavailableRoomType::add);


    System.out.printf("Available room types:\n");
    availableRoomType.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.printf("\nUnavailable room types:\n");
    unavailableRoomType.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output is**:

> Available room types:
>   Standard
>   SuperDeluxe
>       
>   Unavailable room types:
>   Deluxe

Comment: yep, but practically those list elements are come from DB

Comment: @Yasa I edited my post to fit your needs. But in general I suggest creating an own class (`RoomManager` e.g.) that contains the room type logic. If you need some hints let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have duplicates, construct a new [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), then convert it back to [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String type : wholeRoomtype){
    if(!availableroomtype.contains(type) || !unavailableRoomtype.contains(type){
         unavailableRoomtype.add(type);
    }
}
```

here you check whether this type is already added to unavailableRoomtype list. You do nothing if already added.